# Davening on Plane Zmanim

Tags: travel, zemanim, tefilla, halacha

How  do you know when to daven Shachris  on a plane?

Comment: Just wondering: Why not when the sun is up?

Comment: First of all, there is a view that one must follow the zemanim at that location down below, where the sun may not yet be visible. Secondly, it is very difficult to determine when the latest times for Krias Shema and Tefilla occur. For a detailed discussion about this topic, see here: http://www.chaitables.com/Introduction%20to%20the%20Chai%20Air%20Travel%20Tables.htm

Comment: Cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8682

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.chaitables.com/chai_air_eng.php

Comment: Thanx, great resource

Comment: I wonder if somone could make an app of this that would be very worthwhile

Comment: very cool site!

Comment: @SimchasTorah - they do have a Windows-based program. It's surely only a matter of time until they port it to mobile devices.

Comment: I'll definetly have to remember this when I fly from Amsterdam to New York!

Answer (score 3):

There's  online zmanim for flight   From MyZmanim.com

https://www.myzmanim.com/airdemo.aspx

Comment: Joe B, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for linking this resource!