# Alos Hashachar on a flight from Israel to Toronto

Tags: tefilla, travel, zemanim

What time will a person cross alos hashachar (first light of the sun) if he is flying from Israel to Toronto on the night of the [fast of the 17th of Tammuz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeenth_of_Tamuz)? The flight leaves Israel at one in the morning and arrives at 6 in the morning in Toronto.

Comment: Chaim cohen, welcome to Judaism.SE! Your question may have already been addressed here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/davening-on-plane-zmanim

Comment: I am certain the answer to this question will depend on in what year the travel takes place.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.chaitables.com/Introduction%20to%20the%20Chai%20Air%20Travel%20Tables.htm

This link has the information you are looking for.

Comment: It seems to me that that document does not provide the time of _alos hashachar_ on the desired day, but a recommendation of a program that will generate tables that do. The program, Chai Air Travel, generates information for specific flights here: http://www.chaitables.com/chai_air_eng.php . I believe it gives the [result](http://www.chaitables.com/cgi-bin/chai.exe/?from=3&frommonth=7&fromday=19&fromyear=2011&fromhour=1&fromminute=0&fromdst=on&to=111&tomonth=7&today=19&toyear=2011&tohour=6&tominute=0&todst=on&from_timezone=-200&24hr=) as 4:22am for the flight in question.